# How to handle generic ListView pagination with filtered queryset?

Tags: python, django

Code:

```
class MyObjects(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = AllObjects
    template_name = "my_objects.html"
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super(MyObjects, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(added_by=self.request.user).order_by('-last_modified')
```

I have a view that lists user's addings to a table. The problem is pagination is not working properly. I think it is because each time django renders the page, it filters the queryset again, causing only first 10 items to be listed. What can be done to handle this problem? Or should i not use generic view for doing such thing?

Template:

```
<table>
  {% for obj in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{ obj.name}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>

<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item {% if not page_obj.has_previous %}disabled{%endif%}">
      <a class="page-link" {% if page_obj.has_previous %} href="?sayfa={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" {% endif %} aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>
    </li>
    {% for page in page_obj.paginator.page_range %} {% if page == page_obj.number %}
    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">{{ page }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?sayfa={{ page }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
    {% endif %} {% endfor %}
    <li class="page-item {% if not page_obj.has_next %}disabled{%endif%}">
      <a class="page-link" {% if page_obj.has_next %}href="?sayfa={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" {% endif %} aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you want more items to be listed, increase `paginate_by`, if you want to see other items in templates, you'll have to switch from one page to another

Comment: The filter function is not affecting Django's ability to paginate. The pagination is applied *after* the `get_queryset()` method has been called, [in the `get()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L149) method. So your `MyObjects` view class looks like it should work. Can you show us the template?

Comment: I added the template. If the filter is not affecting anything, the problem must be in the template then?

Comment: your paginated object is `object_list` not `page_obj`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. In my template, i used the link "?sayfa={{ page }}". ("sayfa" means page in Turkish, so it's localized version) It's a leftover from my previous pagination which i made with function based view. One way to fix is changing all "sayfa"'s to "page" but since this is not great for localization purposes adding `page_kwarg  = "sayfa"` to my view fixed the problem. Thanks for the answers!